# Method not visible

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create an "agent-like" object, that, given an two indices (agent index, alternative index) returns it's preference for that alternative.

My error is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Integer'
            with actual type `RandomAgent'
In the first argument of `preference', namely `agentNum'
In the expression: preference agentNum alternative
In an equation for `score':
    score agentNum alternative = preference agentNum alternative
```

What I am trying to have is a piece of code that essentially represents a mathematical function such as `A_i(x_j)` where `A_i` is the agent's "score" function for the alternative `x_j`.

I would appreciate any hints on how to proceed. Maybe there is a simpler approach...

Full code below for signatures of other functions

```
module AgentGenerator where

import System.Random

type Alternative = Integer


data RandomAgent = RandomAgent

class Agent a where
    score :: a -> Alternative -> Double

instance Agent RandomAgent where
    score agentNum alternative = preference agentNum alternative

-- TODO: Replace Doubles with Agents
-- Generate `n` agents with `x` alternatives each
generate :: Integer -> Integer -> [Double]
generate agents alternatives = [ preference i j   | i <- [0..(agents-1)], j <- [0..(alternatives-1)] ]

-- Given agent's index and alternative's index return that agent's
-- preference for that alternative
preference :: Integer -> Integer -> Double
preference agent alternative = randomFromSeed $ fromCoord (agent, alternative)

-- Given grid position convert it to a single integer
fromCoord :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
fromCoord (agent, alternative) = (agent * 10^0) + (alternative * 10^1)

-- Generate random value between [0, 1] based on the seed
randomFromSeed :: Integer -> Double
randomFromSeed seed = value
    where (value, gen) = randomR (0.0, 1.0) $ mkStdGen (fromIntegral seed)
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mistype `scope` instead of `score` somewhere?

Comment: Yes! Typo in my post. Thanks.

Comment: The class RandomAgent isn't defined anywhere in the code you've shown. Is that another typo in the question or your actual error (trying to instantiate the wrong class)?

Comment: Hm.. I was trying to make "RandomAgent" an instance of Agent, but also pass it an Integer as a constructor argument... I'm thinking in OOP terms still I guess! Now I'm confused, let me rethink my code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Agent a where ...
```

You define a class called `Agent`...

```
instance RandomAgent Integer where ...
```

...then you declare that `Integer` implements the `RandomAgent` class.

Do you mean to declare a type called `RandomAgent`, containing an `Integer` field, and implementing the `Agent` class? You do that in two steps:

```
data RandomAgent = RandomAgent Integer   -- first declare your RandomAgent type

instance Agent RandomAgent where         -- then declare that it implements your Agent class
    score agent alternative = preference agent alternative
```

(As you're still thinking in OOP terms, I am obliged to point out that you may not need a class (and if you only have a single type implementing your class, you certainly don't)... but if you do, that's how you do it.)

---

Answer the second:

Your `preference` function expects an `Integer` as its first parameter, but is actually given a `RandomAgent` by `score`. One or other of the functions is going to have to *deconstruct* (think “unwrap”) the `RandomAgent` and extract the `Integer` field within.

You might do it in your `score` function like this:

```
instance Agent RandomAgent where
    score (RandomAgent agentNum) alternative = preference agentNum alternative
```

OR you might do it in your `preference` function like this:

```
preference :: RandomAgent -> Integer -> Double
preference (RandomAgent agent) alternative = randomFromSeed $ fromCoord (agent, alternative)
```

Obviously, don't make the changes in both functions, otherwise you'll find yourself passing an `Integer` where a `RandomAgent` is required.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this, but am still getting errors. I've updated my question. Do you recommend making curried functions instead?

Comment: See my edit. Your latest error is not to do with currying or a lack thereof.

Comment: Wow, thanks - I think it's coming together! I also had to change the type constructor to accept an integer: `data RandomAgent = RandomAgent Integer`. But how would I use the `score` function? This doesn't seem to work: `(RandomAgent 1).score 5` :-( And calling score directly, i.e. `score (RandomAgent 1) 5` kind of defeats the whole purpose of creating an `Agent` data type.

Comment: @drozzy: Haskell doesn't have methods.  At all.  Type classes are more like Java interfaces than Java classes - they exist so that *other code* can deal with data just as an instance of the type class, without knowing anything else about it.  So, given your `Agent` class, I could write `maxScore :: Agent a => [a] -> Alternative -> Double` as `maxScore as alt = maximum $ map (`score` alt) as`.  I don't care that it's a `RandomAgent` - whatever implementation of `Agent` you run on, my code will run successfully.

Comment: Furthermore, what's the difference between the ability to do `(RandomAgent 1).score 5` and `score (RandomAgent 1) 5`?